# How to add data to relationship table in ArcGIS 10.1 database design?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase, many-to-many

I have created 2 tables HORSE and VENDOR and a relationship table VENDOR_HORSE
With the foreign key in Horse being the Primary key in VENDOR (VendorID)
and the foreign key in VENDOR being the primary key in HORSE (HorseID).
It is a many to many relationship and ArcGIS automatically creates the link table -.

- yet I had to create the Relationship table which is simple and has extra fields (besides the horseID and vendorID) as Notes (text), Service (coded domain),

and Date (most important to solve many to many matter and have a relational database.
I cannot add data to the VENDOR_HORSE table.
I click on start an edit session, just as I do to add rows to the HORSE and VENDOR tables, with no problems, yet I cannot add rows to the Relationship table.
ESRI help gave instructions for adding rows yet they do not work.
 That is,

1. I selected a row in HORSE,
2. I selected a row in VENDOR,
3. then double clicked on OBJECTID to have the table fields appear in
   the Attribute window
   and NOTHING. What am I missing? 
   Help!
   Thanks
   Bette

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neglect to relate the database type.
But the requirement would be that the database would have to be editable, and the user would have to have privileges granted.
**edit:**.

Since you have stated that you have a fgdb (file geodatabase).
I am trying to understand what you are talking about building a relationship table?
Perhaps you built a [relationship class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_editing_relationships_in_ArcMap/01m90000000q000000/) which is not a table but an Esri object for holding a relationship. 
If you have an actual relationship. 
When you start editing in the spatial table you will see all values from the relate table also.
When you add the spatial object, and input the key value.  If the key value already exists, you will see it auto relate.
You can set the [attribute prompts and use this tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m900000008000000).

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, Brad. I'm sorry I didn't see your response earlier. I have a license for ArcGIS and I've created the geodatabase in that program. There has to be something else. I would like to attach the screenshots that show I have created all the fields in the relationship table (don't see a mechanism to do that here) so I must have  the required permissions or I couldn't have created all the tables. It is an ArcGIS file database created on my computer.

Comment: Go ahead and add the database type to your question.  When you get some more rep you can add screenshots.  Also be sure to always mark your question answered when get the best answer.  This helps create a quality site.

Comment: You are right, Brad. It is a Relationship class which looks like a table yet I understand cannot have rows added to it directly. It is like what is called an intermediate table or link table in IT Relational Database yet it has different behavior in ArcGIS. Thank you for your input. I'll check out your links and hopefully can figure out my problem from there.

Comment: I just found out you cannot have 2 non-spatial tables and have them show up in the attribute window.